# VBScript ScriptControl Eval with variables

Tags: vba, eval, scriptcontrol

Having problems with this and couldn't find a solution online that was more specific to what I am having trouble with.

I have an expression like this

```
pictureFolderFullPath = "C:\Work"

'Create Script Control Obj
Dim sc As ScriptControl
Set sc = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
sc.Language = "VBScript"

Dim content As String
content = sc.Eval("pictureFolderFullPath & "\3.jpg"")
```

Then, the content becomes only "\3.jpg", instead of having the full path of the picture

Comment: You have to add picturefolderpath to the script's namespace. `sc.AddObject "frmSDI", frmSDI, True`

Comment: Okay. I've tried adding the line sc.AddObject("pictureFolderFullPath", pictureFolderFullPath, True) but it says expected =

Comment: You add the module, not the variable.

Comment: So do I run this sc.AddObject "frmSDI", frmSDI, True ?

Because, it didn't work........it says variable not defined for frmSDI

Comment: I postedthe docs. It's your module's name not mine.

Answer (score 1):

*Makes run-time functionality available to a scripting engine.*

**Syntax**

```
ScriptControl.AddObject(name, object[, addMembers])
```

The AddObject method has these parts:

Part    Description

```
name    Required. Name by which the added object is to be known in ScriptControl code.
object  Required. Name of the object exposed at run time.
addMembers  Optional. Boolean value. True if members of object are globally accessible; False if they are not.
```

**Remarks**

Use the AddObject method to make run-time functionality available to a scripting engine. The AddObject method enables a ScriptControl user to provide a set of name/object pairs to the scripting code. The scripting engines may expose the name in any way. In both VBScript and JScript, each name appears as a globally accessible name.